# PUT index resulting in xbyte error

Tags: elasticsearch

When I try to curl PUT I get the following result:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/users2?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
  "mappings": {
    "users": {
      "properties": {
        "email":    { "type": "text"  },
        "first_name":     { "type": "text"  },
        "last_name":    { "type": "text"  },
        "date_joined":     { "type": "date"  },
        "expertise":     { "type": "text"  },
        "institution":    { "type": "text"  },
        "position":     { "type": "text"  }
      }
    }
  }'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "not_x_content_exception",
        "reason" : "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "not_x_content_exception",
    "reason" : "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

the following worked for other ES indices but is failing for the user index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct command:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/users2?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "users": {
      "properties": {
        "email":    { "type": "text"  },
        "first_name":     { "type": "text"  },
        "last_name":    { "type": "text"  },
        "date_joined":     { "type": "date"  },
        "expertise":     { "type": "text"  },
        "institution":    { "type": "text"  },
        "position":     { "type": "text"  }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: missed a bracket! doh!

Comment: Actually, you missed two ;-).